# Add custom font to Font Awesome library

Tags: html, css, svg, fonts, font-awesome

I have explored StackOverflow for an answer to this but all I've come across is how to create your own custom font set that includes both font awesome icons and your own custom fonts.

My problem is that we have already used Font Awesome in our website everywhere and now are in need of adding custom icons to fit the theme of the website. Font Awesome has already been imported in all HTML files. My question is: can I tweak my copy of Font Awesome to include an icon of my own (I have the svg) and add it's own class in the css (For example, if the icon is a face of Napolean, I want to include the icon in my copy of Font Awesome and include a class fa-napolean and assign it a unique unicode of it's own).

Is this possible? I hope I'm clear. And please provide step-by-step procedure for clear understanding. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you.
You can create custom fonts and add into you FA file.
 - https://spin.atomicobject.com/2012/12/16/create-your-own-font-awesome-icons/

Answer (score 0):

You can use IcoMoon App to create your own custom font.

https://icomoon.io/

You can upload your SVG(s) then download the generated fonts and styles and use them along Font Awesome.